# how to interrupt waitforbuttonpress in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to make a gui in which a particular frequency tone will be generated for 5 seconds. it should stop in between of 5 seconds if user press enter or after 5 second in user fails to do so.

how can it be implemented in matlab?

i have thought about waitforbuttonpress but no use in this case because it stop execution until user press enter button so second condition does not meet.

please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sachin - maybe you could try using an alternative to `waitforbuttonpress` and just add a key press callback to your GUI/figure that can stop the playback of the tone.  For example, the following function will create a GUI which simulates a tone on the press of a button.

```
function myToneGui

    % create the GUI
    myGui = figure('Units','normalized',...
                   'Position',[0.39427 0.45093 0.16615 0.13241]);

    % create a button to generate a tone
    myButton = uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton',...
                         'String', 'Generate Tone',...
                         'Units',  'normalized', ...
                         'Position', [0.34169 0.51748 0.28213 0.1958],...
                         'Callback', @genToneCallback); 

    % set the key pressed callback for the button
    set(myButton,'KeyPressFcn',@keyPressedCallback);

    % initialize an audio player object with dummy data
    myToneObj = audioplayer(0,8192);

    function genToneCallback(hObject,eventdata)

        % create a tone for five seconds
        fHz    = 300;
        fs     = 8192;
        lenSec = 5;
        t      = linspace(0,lenSec-1/fs,fs*lenSec);
        tone   = sin(2*pi*t*fHz);

        myToneObj = audioplayer(tone,fs);
        play(myToneObj);

    end

    function keyPressedCallback(hObject,eventdata)
        if isplaying(myToneObj)
            stop(myToneObj); 
        end
    end
end
```

In the above, we create a simple GUI with a button and two callbacks - one for the push button, and one for the key press while the button has focus.  We do this under the assumption that once the button has been pressed (and so the tone is generated) the user will not do anything else until either the tone has ended (after ~five seconds) or he/she has pressed a key (return or otherwise).

The two callbacks are nested within the `myToneGui` function so that both have access to the `myToneObj` audio player variable.  The push button callback can start the player, while the key press callback can stop it (if the player is running).